# three.js: how to add CopyShader after FXAAShader (r58)

Tags: three.js

In postprocessing, I added CopyShader after FXAAShader, for proper rendering even if FXAA are disabed (like a example: webgl_postprocessing2.html).

```
~

renderer.setSize( 320, 240 );  // not full screen

~

fxaa = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );
fxaa.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value = new THREE.Vector2( 1 / 320, 1 / 240 );
composer.addPass( fxaa );

var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
effect.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( effect );
```

This code doesn't work well and the rendered image is smaller than expected.

I'm using r58 and confirmed with Firefox20. What should I do?

Comment: Saying "the code doesn't work well" is not very descriptive. What is the problem and what is your question? Can you provide a live example?

Comment: without postprocessing: http://jsfiddle.net/uxeez/3/,  FXAA only: http://jsfiddle.net/uxeez/1/,  FXAA -> Copy: http://jsfiddle.net/uxeez/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` and `height` of the `THREE.EffectComposer.renderTarget` must match that of the `WebGLRenderer`.

To do that, you create your own `renderTarget` and pass it into the `EffectComposer` constructor.

```
var parameters = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                   format: THREE.RGBFormat, stencilBuffer: false };
var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( width, height, parameters );

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, renderTarget );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uxeez/4/

three.js r.58

Comment: I'm sorry about not checking the examples earnestly (such as webgl_postprocessing_advanced.html).